# What is an un-initialized pointer variable good for?

Tags: c

I was asked this question in an interview.

If there is a pointer that is declared but not initialized like this:
`int *ptr;`

Is it assigned a default value? Or will it be a null pointer? Also, what happens if we try to use this pointer like:

`if(ptr)
{
  //block of code
}`

Will the if condition pass? Also, will this work on debug/release build?

I tried to run this program at home and found that `if` condition passes, and if I try to print the value of the ptr like this:

`printf("%x %d", ptr, *ptr);`

it prints some random value, but it doesn't crash the program.  What is the explanation behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninitialized pointers are good for security vulnerabilities and possibly contributing to seeding random number generators.

Your `if` condition will only skip the block of code if the pointer had been initialized to `NULL` (0).

Because the initialization value is undefined by default it is always considered good practice to initialize to `NULL`.

Your `printf` statement just illustrates the fact that it defaulted to a value other than NULL and in this case it was a valid area of memory that could be dereferenced.

Comment: "and possibly contributing to seeding random number generators" - provided the entropy estimate that goes with it is 0.

Comment: And provided there is a comment stating that's the reason it's uninitialized so somebody doesn't run valgrind, init to null and open up a new security vulnerability (http://digitaloffense.net/tools/debian-openssl/)

Comment: That one was complicated, though. The Debian bug involved a checkin that removed *two* operations to add seed data. One of them contributed data that was always uninitialized, and caused valgrind/purify errors. Removing that was safe, since it wasn't an essential part of the seeding process. The other operation contributed data that typically wasn't uninitialized, and in cases where it was initialized it was critical to security. But that line looked a lot like the other line, so when the other was (perhaps correctly) removed, it (definitely incorrectly) was removed too.

Comment: The bottom line is that seeding your RNG with uninitialized data *cannot* be the basis of the security of your RNG, because uninitialized data isn't suitable as a seed value. But it doesn't do any harm to throw it in on top of some proper randomized data.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing with the RNG.  For a Monte Carlo simulation, it's OK.  For cryptography, it's not.

Answer (score 9):

If it's a global variable (or `static`), it will be implicitly initialized to `NULL`.  Otherwise, its value is undefined.  Therefore, the behaviour of that `if` statement is undefined (i.e. you can make no assumptions about what it might do).  The behaviour of your second example is also undefined (and it could result in a segmentation fault).

Uninitialized pointers are considered dangerous; imagine the consequences of this code:

```
int *ptr;

...

*ptr = 42;  // Dereference pointer and trash somewhere random in memory
```

But note that this might not crash; it may corrupt things silently.

So the convention is to always explicitly initialize it to point at something useful.  If that's not possible (e.g. you don't yet have something to point to), the next best thing you can do is initialise it to `NULL`.  Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer will raise a segmentation fault on most platforms, which will at least help you track down the bug.

Answer (score 2):

> What does an un-initialized pointer variable good for?

Efficiency.  If C automatically initialized pointers to `NULL`, it would waste a whole CPU instruction (or possibly more if the variable had to be stored in main memory instead of a register), and that was unacceptable to the designers of C.  Would you believe programmers these days wanting to sacrifice valuable nanoseconds of runtime just to save a few hours of debugging?

Comment: And not helped by the fact that in C89 you have to define all your variables at the top of a block and (wrongly IMO) a common style is/was to define them all at the top of the function. So people defined variables long before they were initialized, including variables conditionally unused. For the reason you say, and also because spurious initialization can suppress compiler warnings about genuinely unused variables, it was often tempting to define them without initializers. Now you can define variables where you like, there's a lot less reason to define a variable that's conditionally-unused.

Comment: "suppress compiler warnings" - example `int *s = 0, *a = 0; if (condition1) { a = value1; } else if (condition2) { a = value2; } else if (condition3} { s = value3; /* typo, should be a - if I hadn't initialized a to 0, I might have got a compiler warning about this branch */ } printf("%d\n", *a);`. I meant genuinely uninitialized, not genuinely unused...

Comment: I would say orthogonality more than efficiency. Local variables in general are not initialized for efficiency reasons (think large arrays), local pointer variables in particular are not initialized for orthogonality reasons.